# Keycloak Query Params : name of an arbitrarily supplied URL parameter

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

Security Team tested our application & provided the following feedback: 'name of an arbitrarily supplied URL parameter '.

I just wanted to ask if Keycloak application is secure against SQL Injection? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind i got the answer myself.
Since Keycloak have incorporated EntityManager & is using parameterized/named queries where only parameters are changed, structure of the queries is stable so its safe to say that SQL Injection is not possible here as well.

Reference: [https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-persistence-api-jpa](http://Reference:%20https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-persistence-api-jpa)